# OpenLayers 3 SVG vector layer

Tags: svg, vector, openlayers-3

Is there any way in OpenLayers 3 to render a vector layer in SVG instead of canvas ? I'm loading a geojson file now with this code:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: './data/nutsv9_lea.geojson',
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        })
    })],
    renderer: 'dom',
    view: view
});
```

As you can see I'm specifying to use the 'dom' render method. 
When using the developer console in Chrome I see my baselayer (OSM) is rendered in DOM, but my vector layer is still rendered using canvas.

So how can I also render my vector layer in the DOM with svg? 
Or is it simply not supported anymore?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. No support for SVG layers.

Comment: @JonatasWalker thanks!